# Run activity only once, then always run the main one

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, launch

As the title says, Scenario is:
On first time using the app, Show Screen A.
Once you are done with screen A, the button will lead to you Screen B.
From now on and forever, the Screen B will always be main "Screen"(Activity?) when you start the app.
I am trying this 2 days and i can't get it.
Somebody please explain a little detailed, or even better throw me a code.rar so i can research it. I'm going crazy with this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your Activity A as a launcher Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml and inside your Activity A onCreate() you can simply do this

```
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private Editor mEditor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

    if (mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("isfirstTime", true)) {
        mEditor.putBoolean("isFirstTime",false);
        mEditor.apply();
    }else{
         startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
         overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
         finish();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!!!!!!!!!!!! Btw edit editor.putBoolean and editor.apply to mEditor, so people having this problems dont get even more confused. Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to check like this

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mySHaredpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    boolean isFirst = prefs.getBoolean("isfirstTime", true);
    if(isFirst) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivtyA.class);
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_FIRST_TIME, false);
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivty.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Will this [code](http://pastebin.com/AchFZ2k3) work? I tried but suddently android studio got buggy, wont load on emulator... And my pc is kinda slow... is that the right code for 'else' statement?

Comment: I will try it right away once my damn pc loads it, hope it works. Thanks for the help man

Comment: When i run the app, B Activity shows as supposed. When i close app and re-open it, it frozes and terminal on studio displays some gibbersh non-stop. do you know why? It would be so easy if you could just post code sample

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

   public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
      super.onCreate();

      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true)){
          startActivity(this, SecondActivity.class);
          finish(); // Finish the current one, is like forwarding directly to the second one
      }

   }
}
```

Whenever you are done with showing the first activity simple set the shared prefs boolean flag to false:

```
prefs.getEditor.setBoolean("firstStart", false).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("checking",MODE_PRIVATE);

String data = sp.getString("check", "");

if (data.equals("success")) {

//one time proccess code

//with follow code

SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("checking",MODE_PRIVATE);

Editor e1 = sp.edit();

e1.putString("check","success");

e1.commit();


} else {

// code for main

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivty.class);
 startActivity(intent);

}
```