# Do sth. only 1 time on activity creation

Tags: android

How can I make an activity to run some  parts of it's `onCreate` method only in the first creation not in every creation that happens after that. in other word is there anything like *isFirstCreation* for an `Activity` to check as an if expression.
or is there any better method than `onCreate` to do something only 1 time at the time of creation.
thanks

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143835/run-activity-only-once-then-always-run-the-main-one/30143843#30143843

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharedPreference to save a boolean value. Next time just get and check that saved value. Check it here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a boolean value in SharedPreferences and set it to 1 as default value...by running in first time it set to 0...